# Draw canvas text from db?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html, canvas

Im trying some canvas stuff,

here's my code, can anyone shed a light on howto be able to use sqlvariables in the javascript?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function(){
 var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var imageObj = new Image();
 imageObj.onload = function(){
     context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
     context.font = "40pt Calibri";

     context.fillText("Aanvaller1", 75, 260);
     context.fillText("Aanvaller2", 450, 260);

     context.fillText("Mid1", 200, 560);         
     context.fillText("Mid2", 450, 560);

      context.fillText("Verdediger1", 70, 860);
      context.fillText("Verdediger2", 425, 860);

      context.fillText("Keeper", 310, 1010);
    };
 imageObj.src = "voetbalveld2.png"; 
};
</script>


<canvas id="myCanvas" width="804" height="1200"></canvas>
```

So this will draw my text as desired, but i want to be able to query the db and put the names from the db on the places where i now hardcoded text.
Thnx in advance.

I do NOT need code how to query db's etc, i just need to know how to use it in combination with js and canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Javascript runs in the client browser, and the SQL database is stored on the server. What you need is the ability to use the client side code, to query the server to retrieve the data. What I'm thinking is some intermediary language inbetween (PHP would be my choice here), and Ajax.

So your Javascript can call a PHP page with an Ajax request; the PHP returns an XML/Json with all of your variables in a structured format, that the Js can then parse and plug into the canvas code.

```
getNames.php
--------------
// mysql stuff goes here
$arr = array('name1' => 'Aanvaller1', 'name2' => 'Aanvaller2', 'name3' => 'Mid1');
echo json_encode($arr);
```

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var json = null;
    $.ajax({
        'async': false,
        'global': false,
        'url': 'getNames.php',
        'dataType': "json",
        'success': function (data) {
            json = data;
        }
    });
  });
```

You now have a variable called 'json' with your mysql data in there. Parse it and stick it into your canvas.

Comment: hmm, thats a bunch of mumbo jumbo to me there.

Comment: any real live examples of my question anywhere?

Comment: Added code, have a look. I've used jQuery to simplify the ajax call.

Comment: thnx man, ill look into this in a min, i was just trying it whouth ajax, and that also works?

Comment: I just define the variables before the javasscript, it works fine, why is your way better? (im here to learn ofc)

Comment: I thought you wanted to read the values from a database? Javascript cannot query a database. You need a server side language for that. Hence the PHP code, and the Ajax to read those values.

Comment: Now for the next part though

Comment: Im able to draw the names FROM the db correctly onto the image, its a standalon php file right now, howver IF i include the .php in anotherpage the canvas will NOT draw, any thoughts? ( i did use relative paths etc)

Comment: Not without seeing your code, sorry. Pastebin it and edit your post to add the link.

Comment: sure :) thnx man  --- here you go http://pastebin.com/GwtxY84s  DO NOTE THAT IM A NOOBY IN PHP MYSQL JAVASCRIPT :P